# reading txt file into data frame in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a text file in the following format:

```
   "C1","name1","type1": 2
   "C1","name2","type4": 6
   "C2","name1","type2": 1
   "C1","name3","type1": 10
```

I tried:

```
   db<- read.table("myfile.txt")
```

but this stores the file as two column and store the values as "name1", I also tried :

```
  db<- read.csv("myfile.txt", header= FALSE)
```

but this stores the last two columns as one column:

```
    C1   name1     type1:2
    C1   name2     type4:6
    C2   name1     type2:1
    C1   name3     type1:10
```

How can store the last two columns as two separate columns

```
    C1   name1     type1  2
    C1   name2     type4  6
    C2   name1     type2  1
    C1   name3     type1  10
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `separate` from `tidyr` package can help you.

```
   tidyr::separate(db, col = 3, into = c("type", "number"), sep = ":")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just split the columns after reading it trhough `read.csv`

```
x = read.csv("myfile.txt", header = F, sep = ",")
y = matrix(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x$V3), ":")), ncol = 2, byrow = T)

x$V3 = y[, 3]
x$V4 = y[, 4]

  V1    V2    V3  V4
1 C1 name1 type1   2
2 C1 name2 type4   6
3 C2 name1 type2   1
4 C1 name3 type1  10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
d1 <- read.table(header=FALSE, sep=":", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text=
'   "C1","name1","type1": 2
   "C1","name2","type4": 6
   "C2","name1","type2": 1
   "C1","name3","type1": 10')

d2 <- read.table(header=FALSE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text=d1$V1)

cbind(d2, d1V2=d1$V2)
#> cbind(d2, d1V2=d1$V2)
#     V1    V2    V3 d1V2
#1    C1 name1 type1    2
#2    C1 name2 type4    6
#3    C2 name1 type2    1
#4    C1 name3 type1   10
```